# Trigger one AWS Lambda after the completion of n Running AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, triggers, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Is there a way to trigger one aws lambda after the successful completion of ***n*** parallel running lambdas.

Lets call the:

- parallel lambda **L1**
- final lambda **L2**

Some previously running task trigger ***n*** lambdas **L1** all running on a group based triggers.
Suppose there are 5 **L1s** of group 1 and 7 **L1s** of group 2

My aim is to trigger **L2** when any of the above group completes its execution.

If all group 1 lambdas completed successfully then ony one **L2** trigger for group 1 and same for group 2. In short i am looking for grouped trigger for **L2**.

Please note: Both lambdas are running in VPC and I am using SNS to connect them together and I did not want to use a monitoring task.

Please consider scenario when 3 out of 5 lambdas are already done. 4 and 5 complete at the same time which one of them will trigger **L2**.

Important: **Internet access is blocked in VPC**

Comment: Maybe StepFunctions could help https://aws.amazon.com/de/step-functions/

Comment: did it support dynamic setup. like from the one lambda that trigger all the lambda **L1s**.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda does not support this feature natively and, while you could conceivably build it with some combination of DynamoDB atomic counters and DynamoDB streams triggers, you should almost certainly use [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

You're trying to coordinate the components of a distributed application composed of microservices, and that's precisely what Step Functions is designed to do.

Comment: question still remains how can i configure a step function while my **L1** is now fix. The whole process is dynamic. Also note that internet access is blocked in VPC as only way Lambdas are communicating is via sns

Comment: @JugrajSingh You could dynamically build the Step Function State Machine before starting any task. Then your SNS is triggering a Lambda function which will start an execution of the State Machine. It's possible, but it will result in lots of State Machines if you can't reuse them somehow.

Comment: @s.hesse State Machines can be deleted? Also the problem is how **L1** will communicate its completion